# Why does this code initialize an object and then make another object equal to it?

Tags: c#, reference, refactoring

Here's the function:

```
private static void AddToTree(TreeNode target, DataRow dataRow)
{
    var node2 = new TreeNode(dataRow["name"].ToString())
    {
        ImageIndex = target.ImageIndex,
        SelectedImageIndex = target.SelectedImageIndex,
        Tag = dataRow
    };
    TreeNode node = node2;
    target.Nodes.Add(node);
}
```

I see similar code throughout the codebase. Why not just add `node2` to the target nodes and not create another variable? Am I missing something?

Comment: I agree - this looks redundant.

Comment: Just to clarify some terminology - this code isn't making another object equal to `node2`, its simply making another local variable point to the same object that the `node2` variable points to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not missing anything. This code is redudant.

```
TreeNode node = node2; //<--- Assign the object reference of node2 to node. 
                       //     There is no object copy or wathever.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'think that you can replace

```
target.Nodes.Add(node2);
```

You can take copy of reference, but in order to compare in second time with result query or another treatment, but with just this code, you can replace